# Cannot use foreach to iterate through a ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel file I created:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string AString { get; set; }
    public string BString { get; set; }
    public string CString { get; set; }
    public string DString { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ADate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset BDate { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to run a for-each statement to iterate thru the items but I am getting

> MyViewModel does not contain a public definition for `GetEnumerator`

Here is my statement that tries to use it:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyViewModel model)
{
    foreach(var item in model)
    {
        //add code here
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, can anyone help?

EDIT: The ViewModel is accepting data passed to it via an AJAX-get call. I just fill the fields as necessary. I did this because I did not want to have a method that accepts over 20 parameters inline (string a, string b, string c, ...). It made more sense to make a ViewModel that has all possible fields and the AJAX call would populate those fields accordingly. What I want to do after that is pass those values into the service but they have to be changed a bit to work with the old service.

The service expects:

```
serviceName(ID, GUID, NAME, parameters)
ID - string
GUID - GUID
NAME - string
parameters - new parameter { name = "[model.Name]", value = new List<string>(){ "[model.value]" }}
```

the [model.Name] and [model.Value] is filled by iterating "if using the right term" thru the model I created to fill those slots.

Comment: Because MyViewModel is not IEnumerable. If you want to loop through all the members in a model, you need to do it explicitly or through reflection. I'm not sure what you want to accomplish in the loop though, if you are doing validation you need to do that based on what the field contains, and at that point you are better off writing "if" statements for each member. What are you trying to accomplish inside the loop?

Comment: Can you give me an example of explicitly doing it please?  I am a month into learning C# and MVC.  I am building a List of items to pass to an endPoint.

Comment: There's no collection in your code over which to loop.  What are you trying to actually *do* in that loop?

Comment: Explicitly means write an if statement for each member, ie: `if (model.AString == "something")` etc for each one. Again, it would help more if you explained what you wanted the loop to do.

Comment: I am trying to build a list to pass certain items in the collection to a service.  I wanted to find a short way to do it since the viewmodel will get very large over time.  This is just a start to make it work.

Comment: _"I am trying to build a list"_ - then **show** what output you expect or are trying to build in your question. _"I cannot iterate over a single model"_ isn't really answerable. Please read [ask]. Now you're getting answers suggesting to use reflection, which almost most certainly is not what you're looking for. If you just need a `List<string>` containing the property values, for example, then say so. Then it's as easy as `new List<string> { model.AString, model.BString, ... }`.

Comment: Apologies for not being more specific.  The viewmodel is accepting data passed to it via an AJAX get call.  I just fill the fields as necessary.  I did this because I did not want to have a method that accepts over 20 parameters inline (string a, string b, string c, ...).  It made more sense to make a viewmodel that has all possible fields and the AJAX call would populate those fields accordingly.  What I want to do after that is pass those values into the service but they have to be changed a bit to work with the old service.

Comment: I was trying to go through each item in the viewmodel and massage the data to fit the service

Comment: I will update the main question with that now.

Comment: "*What I want to do after that is pass those values into the service*" - if you loop over them, how will `item` know which value it is in order to pass to which parameter on the service?   (A: pass a dictionary, but that's just getting silly).  Just use them explicitly and use (some of) the answers to the question to learn about collections/lists.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.  As I mentioned before, I am new to C# and figuring it out.  This was very helpful.  I will continue to study and learn from these great examples.  Thank you.

Comment: C# is not JavaScript.  What you're doing is possible in JavaScript, but not in C#.  To be iterable, you need to implement IEnumerable.  This is usually done for arrays and Lists.  I would not recommend implementing IEnumerable in your ViewModel class just so you can iterate over the properties, either.

Answer (score 3):

Here's you can loop through all the public properties in your model by using reflection:

```
var properties = typeof(MyViewModel).GetProperties();
foreach(var property in properties) 
{
    var propertyName = property.Name;
    var propertyValue = property.GetValue(model);
    //Now process the property
}
```

Note however, that reflection introduces a penalty in performance and should not be used if there are better alternatives. In your case, it looks like you could very well declare a couple of arrays or dictionaries to store your data. For example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel
    {
        TheStrings = new string[4];
        TheDates = new DateTimeOffset[2];
    }

    public string TheStrings { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeOffset TheDates { get; private set; }
}
```

Now you access `model.TheStrings[0]` instead of `model.AString`, and so on; using a dictionary with keys A,B,C,D would further improve readability but the idea is the same. Now you can easily `foreach` your strings and dates.

Comment: Just be aware that using reflection is costly. Do not use it for large iterations. Most of time, it's not that complex to manually manipulate properties...

Comment: Sure! I'm improving my answer, thanks.

Comment: You generally do not need reflection in application code. Please don't suggest that OP does (especially since they're saying they're very new to C#) if the actual problem isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

foreach works for any object collections which implements `IEnumerable` and arrays. In your code,MyViewModel is a POCO class which is not implementing Innumerable.

If your posted model is a collection of MyViewModel, You can loop through those. For example, If you are posting a list of customers/Products, you will be doing something like this

```
public ActionResult MyMethod (IEnumerable<MyViewModel> model)
{
  foreach(var product in model)
  {
    //You can access each property here
   //product.AString
  }
}
```

If you simple want to read the different property values of the posted model, You do not need the foreach. Simply, read each property

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyViewModel model)
{
  var aStringVal =  model.AString;
  var bStringVal = model.BString;
  //Do something with the values.
}
```

If you still want to get all the properties of your single instance of MyViewModel, You should use reflection to get that as Konamiman wrote in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

C# is completely different to JavaScript:

- In C#, foreach loops through every object in a sequence of objects (IEnumerable)
- In JavaScript, foreach loops through the value of every property in a single object.

In C# you cannot easily loop through every property in a class, nor should you attempt to do so. 
 Instead, if you want several properties of the same type, use [List<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<string>   MyStrings { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> MyDates   { get; set; }
}

foreach (string s in model.MyStrings)
{
}

foreach (DateTime d in model.MyDates)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> based on newer info added to the question

If the parameters can change on each call, then using a viewmodel with fixed properties would not suit your case.

Remember that C# is strongly-typed, you can't just send whatever values you want, only the ones already defined.

If the parameters can change for each call then you can't use a fixed viewmodel, so change the method to a dictionary of name+value:

```
 public ActionResult MyMethod(IDictionary<string, string> model)
 {
     var parameters = new List<Parameter>();
     foreach (var kvp in model)
     {
         parameters.Add(new parameter { name = kvp.Key, value = new List<string> { key.Value }});
     }
```

this may also be suitable if you have lots of values.

You could use a ViewModel that inherits or has a dictionary property, but this is the essential part

---

If the parameters are always the same, then use the values explicitly:

```
 public ActionResult MyMethod(IDictionary<string, string> model)
 {
     var parameters = new List<Parameter>();
     parameters.Add(new parameter { name = "AString", value = new List<string> { model.AString }});
     parameters.Add(new parameter { name = "BString", value = new List<string> { model.BString }});
```

but it's most likely the case that the client is defining the parameters.